# Cannot use "parent" when current class scope has no parent in magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

I have used LOF_Affliate module in one of my projects as its module version is (1.0.0). Recently I am upgrading the Magento version 2.3.5 to 2.4.3. After upgrading I am facing the below issue.

"Deprecated Functionality: Cannot use "parent" when current class scope has no parent in /var/www/html/app/code/Lof/Affiliate/Controller/Router.php on line 40 "

In magento 2.4.3, "parent is deprecated"?

Is anyone having any solution for this, if you have please guide me.

Comment: try to contact the extension vendor for the upgraded version of the extension, which is compatible with new magento version.

Answer (score 0):

it happen because di unable resolve implementation class for some interfaces in development mode  to solve it need execute di compile command

```
rm -rf generated 
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```